# Wildfly ignores Library in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I have two Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64) with Java 1.8.0_171 machines running a Wildfly 13.0.0.Final.

I have following Maven dependency in my pom.xml of my web application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>25.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

When running the web application on the first server, it is complaining about a missing method:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:168)
at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:141)
...
```

Strangely enough, on the second server it is running smoothly with the same configuration.

Here is a list of all jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory:

- activation-1.1.jar
- flute-1.3.0.gg2.jar
- iron-resizable-behavior-2.1.1.jar
- nd4j-api-0.9.1.jar
- orchid-1.2.1.jar
- vizcomponent-2.0.jar
- animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
- font-roboto-1.1.0.jar
- iron-scroll-target-behavior-2.1.1.jar
- nd4j-base64-0.9.1.jar
- paper-behaviors-2.1.1.jar
- webcomponents-helper-0.2.0.jar
- app-layout-2.0.4.jar
- fontawesomelabel-1.4.0.jar
- iron-validatable-behavior-2.1.0.jar
- nd4j-buffer-0.9.1.jar
- paper-icon-button-2.1.0.jar
- webcomponentsjs-1.1.0.jar
- app-layout-addon-0.9.22.jar
- freemarker-2.3.23.jar
- itextpdf-5.5.12.jar
- nd4j-common-0.9.1.jar
- paper-ripple-2.1.1.jar
- websocket-api-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
- atmosphere-runtime-2.4.24.vaadin1.jar
- gentyref-1.2.0.vaadin1.jar
- j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
- nd4j-context-0.9.1.jar
- paper-styles-2.1.0.jar
- websocket-client-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
- autocomplete-0.2.2.jar
- geojson-jackson-1.2.jar
- jackson-0.9.1.jar
- nd4j-jackson-0.9.1.jar
- polymer-2.5.0.jar
- websocket-common-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
- base64-2.3.9.jar
- googleanalyticstracker-2.1.0.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
- nd4j-native-0.9.1-android-arm.jar
- prettytime-4.0.1.Final.jar
- xalan-2.7.2.jar
- bitcoinj-core-0.14.3.jar
- gson-2.8.2.jar
- jackson-core-2.9.1.jar
- nd4j-native-0.9.1-android-x86.jar
- protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar
- xchange-binance-4.3.10.jar
- cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar
- guava-25.0-jre.jar
- jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar
- nd4j-native-0.9.1-linux-ppc64le.jar
- proxytoys-1.0.jar
- xchange-bitfinex-4.3.10.jar
- checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar
- gwt-ol3-2.1.jar
- javacpp-1.3.3.jar
- nd4j-native-0.9.1-linux-x86_64.jar
- qrcode-2.1.jar
- xchange-bittrex-4.3.10.jar
- commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- hdf5-1.10.0-patch1-1.3-linux-ppc64le.jar
- javaee-api-8.0.jar
- nd4j-native-0.9.1-macosx-x86_64.jar
- reflections-0.9.11.jar
- xchange-coinegg-4.3.10.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
- hdf5-1.10.0-patch1-1.3-linux-x86.jar
- javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar
- nd4j-native-0.9.1-windows-x86_64.jar
- rescu-2.0.2.jar
- xchange-coinmarketcap-4.3.10.jar
- commons-codec-1.11.jar
- hdf5-1.10.0-patch1-1.3-linux-x86_64.jar
- javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
- nd4j-native-0.9.1.jar
- sac-1.3.jar
- xchange-core-4.3.10.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- hdf5-1.10.0-patch1-1.3-macosx-x86_64.jar
- javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
- nd4j-native-api-0.9.1.jar
- scrypt-1.4.0.jar
- xchange-cryptopia-4.3.10.jar
- commons-compress-1.8.jar
- hdf5-1.10.0-patch1-1.3-windows-x86.jar
- javax.mail-1.6.0.jar
- nd4j-native-platform-0.9.1.jar
- serializer-2.7.2.jar
- xchange-gdax-4.3.10.jar
- commons-io-2.6.jar
- hdf5-1.10.0-patch1-1.3-windows-x86_64.jar
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar
- nearestneighbor-core-0.9.1.jar
- shadycss-1.1.1.jar
- xchange-hitbtc-4.3.10.jar
- commons-lang3-3.7.jar
- hdf5-1.10.0-patch1-1.3.jar
- javaxt-core-1.8.2.jar
- neko-htmlunit-2.28.jar
- signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar
- xchange-kraken-4.3.10.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- hdf5-platform-1.10.0-patch1-1.3.jar
- jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
- neoitertools-1.0.0.jar
- slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta2.jar
- xchange-kucoin-4.3.10.jar
- commons-math3-3.4.1.jar
- highcharts-2.1.jar
- jettison-1.3.8.jar
- nv-websocket-client-1.30.jar
- slf4j-nop-1.8.0-beta2.jar
- xchange-liqui-4.3.10.jar
- commons-net-3.6.jar
- htmlunit-2.29.jar
- jetty-client-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
- objenesis-2.6.jar
- snakeyaml-1.12.jar
- xchange-okcoin-4.3.10.jar
- commons-text-1.2.jar
- htmlunit-core-js-2.28.jar
- jetty-http-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
- okhttp-2.7.2.jar
- stax-api-1.0.1.jar
- xchange-poloniex-4.3.10.jar
- confirmdialog-3.1.1.jar
- httpclient-4.5.4.jar
- jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
- okio-1.6.0.jar
- stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
- xchange-yobit-4.3.10.jar
- core-1.51.0.0.jar
- httpcore-4.4.7.jar
- jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3-android-arm.jar
- stream-2.7.0.jar
- xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
- cssparser-0.9.24.jar
- httpmime-4.5.4.jar
- jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3-android-x86.jar
- ta4j-core-0.11.jar
- xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
- datavec-api-0.9.1.jar
- iron-a11y-keys-behavior-2.1.1.jar
- joda-time-2.9.2.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3-linux-armhf.jar
- v-ol3-2.1.jar
- xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
- datavec-dataframe-0.9.1.jar
- iron-behaviors-2.1.1.jar
- joor-0.9.6.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3-linux-ppc64le.jar
- vaadin-client-compiled-8.4.5.jar
- xmlworker-5.5.12.jar
- deeplearning4j-core-0.9.1.jar
- iron-checked-element-behavior-2.1.1.jar
- json-20170516.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3-linux-x86.jar
- vaadin-context-menu-2.0.0.jar
- xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
- deeplearning4j-modelimport-0.9.1.jar
- iron-flex-layout-2.0.3.jar
- jsoup-1.11.2.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3-linux-x86_64.jar
- vaadin-push-8.4.5.jar
- xstream-1.4.10.jar
- deeplearning4j-nn-0.9.1.jar
- iron-form-element-behavior-2.1.3.jar
- jsr305-2.0.1.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3-macosx-x86_64.jar
- vaadin-sass-compiler-0.9.13.jar
- xz-1.6.jar
- deeplearning4j-ui-components-0.9.1.jar
- iron-icon-2.1.0.jar
- lombok-1.16.16.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3-windows-x86.jar
- vaadin-server-8.4.5.jar
- emoji-java-4.0.0.jar
- iron-icons-2.0.1.jar
- mail-1.5.0-b01.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3-windows-x86_64.jar
- vaadin-shared-8.4.5.jar
- error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar
- iron-iconset-svg-2.2.1.jar
- markdown4j-2.2-cj-1.1.jar
- openblas-0.2.19-1.3.jar
- vaadin-slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar
- fastutil-6.5.7.jar
- iron-media-query-2.1.0.jar
- mongo-java-driver-3.4.0.jar
- openblas-platform-0.2.19-1.3.jar
- vaadin-themes-8.4.5.jar
- findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar
- iron-meta-2.1.1.jar
- morphia-1.3.2.jar
- opencsv-2.3.jar
- viritin-2.1.jar

Comment: Are you deploying the same EAR or WAR to your container/appserver? No errors during the deployment? is this a runtime error?

Comment: yes i deploy the same ROOT.war to both servers (copy into deployments). no errors during deployment. this is a runtime exception, which occurs, when the  code is executed, which relies on Guava.

Comment: Possibly the container contains another Guava version on $serverpath/lib, did you check it?

Comment: yes i checked that - there is guava 25.0-jre in the wildfly's module dir. but this version is the same i am using. how is this possible, that two servers react differently?

Comment: Both are JEE implementations, but the way it is implemented may be different, since the servers you are using are different. Did you try to put this guava 25.0-jre inside your project and check what happens?

Comment: the guava 25.0-jre is already in my project (defined as maven dependency AND - as a result of maven packaging - in the WEB-INF/lib-folder)
the same ROOT.war is deployed to identical servers - however - only one server is  loading the guava dependency into the class path... very strange!?

Comment: Please provide a list of all jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory. Right now I suspect that you have two different versions of the reflections jar in your application because I have seen this sort of behaviour before.

Comment: @SteveC i added the list of jars.

Answer (score 1):

Windfly brings Guava as it's own dependencies:
https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/dependencies.html

In the latest Windfly version it is Guava 18.

The [`Sets`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) class is only available since version 20.

My best guess is that both version are available in the class path of you application and it's a matter of coincidence which version your app ends up using.
Therefore to keep the dependencies separated you should defined a JBoss module and defined your dependencies explicitly there.
How to do this probably is beyond the scope of this answer but can be found [here](https://jboss-modules.github.io/jboss-modules/manual/#concepts) and [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly).

Comment: no, the installed version of wildfly (13) has a Guava 25 dependency (.../wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/google/guava/main/guava-25.0-jre.jar)

Comment: All non-java-ee classes in a WildFly implementation are invisible to applications unless specifically enabled using XML configuration files or `Dependencies` elements in module manifest.mf files.